# How do you calculate $25^{11} \pmod{341}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How do you calculate $25^{11} \pmod{341}$?

I understand you have to split the exponent into $11 = 1 + 2 + 8$?

Comment: The fact that you say $11 = 1 + 2 + 8$ hints at [square-and-multiply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), which is indeed one way to do such computations more efficiently. Other tricks include using the Chinese Remainder Theorem and Fermat's Little Theorem.

Answer (score 9):

Note that $ 341 = 11 \cdot 31 $ and hence it is sufficient to fine the residues of $ 25^{11} $ modulo $ 11 $ and $ 31 $ and then apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

By Fermat's Little Theorem, $ 25^{10} \equiv 1 \mod 11 \implies 25^{11} \equiv 25 \equiv 3 \mod 11 $.

Also note that $ 25^4 \equiv (-6)^4 \equiv 5^2 \equiv 25 \mod 31 $ and hence $ 25^3 \equiv 1 \mod 31 $ which implies that $ 25^{11} \equiv 25^2 \equiv 5 \mod 31 $.

Therefore, $ 25^{11} \equiv 36 \mod 341 $ after applying the CRT.